# How can we display database query in azure application insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

Our application is using azure application insights. What I read is that, using application insights end to end tracking, we can even get the query which gets executed at database and how much time that query took.

But as shown in the screenshot, azure app insights shows me that there are 3 calls made to database but not the actual query that was executed against the database in those calls.

What I need to know is that what i need to do inorder to get the query that was executed against the database?

[image]

Comment: It's a .net core project or .net framework project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the application insights can track sql query. But note that there are some changes in the latest version of application insights nuget package, which makes it does not automatically track sql query.

You can do it via the workaround below.

Assume you're using the `.net core` web project. Then you need to downgrade the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore` to version `2.12.0`.

Here is my test result with version 2.12.0 of that package:

[image]

And also, you can use other workarounds, see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Announcements/issues/28) for more details.

Comment: How would I then query the AppInsights log with KQL to find that request which included that specific SQL Command?

Comment: Looking for answer on how to query this too...

Answer (score 7):

This is one of breaking changes as part of SDK 2.14.

You just need to simply modify ConfigureServices() with the line below for ASP.NET Core:

```
services.ConfigureTelemetryModule<DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule>((module, o) => { module.EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation = true; });
```

and for ASP.NET modify ApplicationInsights.config file:

```
<Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector">, 
<EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation>true</EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation>
</Add>
```

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Announcements/issues/28