# Setting up Advanced SQL Tracking with App Insights

Tags: sql, azure-application-insights

I work for a corporation, and we are trying to set up Application Insights for one of our products.  We have the instrumentation key and everything integrated into the code where necessary, but we still can't see all the information we want...

The goal is for our screen to look like this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/media/asp-net-dependencies/3-end-to-end.png

We've been using this link as a reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies

We have installed Microsoft.Data.SQLClient NuGet  Package, and the XML line, but the advanced SQL data still does not show in App Insights.  We are running things locally on IIS Express, our project runs, and when we interact with the web app we see spikes in our performance graph, so we know it is collecting some metrics.

We apparently need to be running SDK Version 'rddp'.  We are using the version 'rddf' and 'rdddsd' which indicates dependencies are collected via DiagnosticSource or EventSource callbacks, and hence full SQL query aren't being captured.

We got the information about the SDK Version by running this command in Logs in App Insights: dependencies | where timestamp > ago(1d) | summarize count() by cloud_RoleInstance, SDK version

Here is [the output from that command.](https://gxcuf89792.i.lithium.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/201856i81824296341AFE20/image-size/large?v=1.0&px=999)

Our team has scoured the internet and every other stack overflow questions and it feels like we've tried everything.  I have found similar posts where people have similar problems, but the fixes that worked for them haven't worked for us.

Comment: which version of application insights sdk you're using? and are you using a .net core or .net framework web project?

Comment: please have a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62593828/5765399

Comment: We're using .Net

Comment: SDK version rddf:2.10.0-32157

Comment: please try the answers in the link in the above comments:). It should work, we have tested it and worked.

Comment: I have tried upgrading a couple times but I get this error and cannot run my code: Error NU1605 Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.ApplicationInsights from 2.14.0 to 2.10.0. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
 NameOfProject -> Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web 2.14.0 -> Microsoft.ApplicationInsights (>= 2.14.0) 
 NameOfProject -> Microsoft.ApplicationInsights (>= 2.10.0)  C:\Users\******.csproj 1

Comment: Did you ever fix this? I've got the same issue. I have the latest SDK (2.15), have added the EnableSqlCommandTextInstrumentation value in AppInsights.config, am using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient and still getting no SQL command text. The SDK version is apparently "rddf:2.15.0-44797" and like you I have no idea how to get that to be rddp.